# is there counter endpoint for Azure AD Graph API in US Gov resource

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-gov

We are using azure ad graph api to get user details . I was checking counter endpoint for Azure US Gov in US Gov developer guide but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Azure AD Graph API is not listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-developer-guide#endpoint-mapping.

MS Graph API seems to be available at https://graph.microsoft.us/. You can use it to get user details as well.